# Why does `gsub` call `to_hash`?

Tags: ruby, dsl

I am writing a DSL. I don't want users to have to quote the arguments to pass strings, therefore I overwrite `method_missing` to convert an unknown method to a string. In the following example, `create` is the DSL method, and I wanted user to type `arg1` and `arg2` without the quotes.

```
def method_missing(m, *arg)
  m.to_s
end
def create(*args)
  arg1.gsub(#do something here)
end

create arg1 arg2
```

However, this raises and error when I use `gsub` on the 'string':

```
'gsub': can't convert String to Hash (String#to_hash gives String) (TypeError)
```

I guess the `method_missing` overwriting is messed it up since it looks like `gsub` is calling `String#to_hash`, which is not a method in `String`, thus it is routed to `method_missing`.

I am wondering why `gsub` calls `String#to_hash`, or whether there is any other way to let users of the DSL not have to type quotes, without overwriting `method_missing`.

Comment: What is the relation between `arg1`, `arg2` and `args` in `create`?

Comment: arg1,2 are just arguments passed to method create, maybe i should add something like arg1=arg.first before gsub line, so its less confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) does different things depending on the argument count and types, and if a block was given:

> ```
> gsub(pattern, replacement) → new_str
> gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str
> gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str
> gsub(pattern) → enumerator
> ```

The second one is documented as:

> If the second argument is a `Hash`, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

But how to distinguish it from the first? Both take two arguments! That's a little bit complicated but in your case Ruby (well, the reference implementation called CRuby or MRI to be exact) starts with checking if the second argument has the internal type `T_HASH` (it doesn't as it's most likely `T_STRING` due to `#to_s`), then it checks if `#to_hash` can be called. Either because it responds to it or `#method_missing` can instead. You have defined it so Ruby calls it. However it doesn't return a `T_HASH` and that is the cause of the exception you've posted.

A possible solution is defining `main.method_missing` and not `Object#method_missing` (as `String` inherits from `Object`):

```
def self.method_missing(m, *arg)
  m.to_s
end
```

However I recommend sticking to quotes or writing your own small parser for this kind of file if it shouldn't adhere to Ruby's syntax. Using `*_missing` may be the cause of confusing or unhelpful error messages. Or even none (I guess `create arg1 arg2` should've been `create arg1, arg2`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` probably uses `method_missing` itself somewhere, so it seems that defining it globally there is causing internal issues with the method call. If you're going to use `method_missing` make sure you always define it in a module or a class:

```
module CoolDSL
  def self.method_missing(m, *arg)
    m.to_s
  end

  def self.create(*args)
    args[0].gsub(/1/, "2")
  end

  def self.do_thing
    create arg1 arg2
  end
end

CoolDSL.do_thing
```

Naturally, that's not exactly useful as a DSL, so you'll want to learn the power of `instance_eval` and `yield`. I like [this guide](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby).

Comment: hmm. Not sure how this guide solve the problem of no need to add quotes to arguments passed to dsl method. It's "User", "Post" words are actually predefined classes.

Comment: I was mentioning it as a good place to start if you want to learn some more Ruby DSL tricks. My answer explains why you were getting that error with gsub. (Just make sure to properly scope your method_missing)

Comment: `gsub` does not use `method_missing`, and 99% of the time you use `method_missing` you are doing something wrong that you would regret sometimes in the future

Comment: @bjhaid I agree that using `method_missing` can get dangerous real fast, and make your code less readable and harder to debug.